# Wrong key behavior

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I am encountering a very weird error recently, that I cannot figure out to solve.

I have an Asus S301L with Ubuntu 12.04 and an Italian keyboard; every time I log in, some key on my keyboard does not work properly:

1. <kbd>p</kbd> produces <kbd>*</kbd>
2. <kbd>0</kbd> produces <kbd>/</kbd>
3. <kbd>-</kbd> produces <kbd>+</kbd>

But also others, for example, it took quite some time for me to just write this message.

The only way to have things again to work properly is to type from a terminal:

```
setxkbmap it
```

That command takes a keyboard layout configuration from the folder

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/
```

And it starts again to work, just for a (indefinite) duration of time , then, things, again, are wrong.

The output of the locale command is:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_TIME=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_NAME=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Where are you setting your layout options? What desktop environment are you using?

Comment: The layout options are present in the folder      /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/  and I use the Gnome DE. Thanks

Comment: I mean where do you set the layout? Do you use a terminal command (if so, which command, which file runs it etc) or do you use the Gnome settings? Please [edit] your questions and answer that and also include the output of the `locale` command.

Comment: I set my layout using the command `setxkbmap it` from terminal , this is the only one I use. I tryed to use the gnome settings, but nothing changed...

Comment: I also edited with the info you asked me...

Comment: I know you said you tried changing in the settings but was it the way I describe in my answer or did you change something in the Regional Settings tab instead?

Comment: I tried to change the settings using the way you described below, but nothing. I also made some attempts changing various configurations in the regional settings...but nothing... :(

Comment: Found this issue, it helped me figure it out. Turned out I was pranked at work, my laptop does not have a numpad, still the key was pressed. Making these exact and only these key change according to the authors description.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe sounds like the desktop environment (DE), Gnome in your case, is switching back to the default settings every now and then and that's what is screwing with your keyboard layout. The simplest solution would be to set the correct settings from the Gnome settings menu.

Open the System Settings, click on Keyboard, then on "Layout Settings":

[image]
On the next screen, remove any keyboard layouts that you don't want:

[image]

---

If you still have this problem, you might want to also set the Regional Settings (System Settings => Language and Region) to whatever you prefer as well. However, I have always mixed US English layouts with European style number and regional settings so I doubt this is the issue.